# Programmatically revealing a node in angular-tree-component

Tags: angular, treeview

Trying to achieve a simple thing with [angular-tree-component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-tree-component) - the component is so great that I bet it is something obvious that I am overlooking in the [API](https://angular2-tree.readme.io/docs/treemodel).

I want to programmatically reveal a node, ie. expanding all its ancestors.

```
const node = this.tree.treeModel.getNodeById(+id);
if (node) {
  this.tree.treeModel.setFocusedNode(node);
  // now what? :)
}
```

Neither of the drill methods work for me, `setFocusedNode` does not reveal the node, it just marks it focused. Help anyone?

Comment: I've looked also in the API and only found expandAll on TreeLevel, but no expand for a node. Perhaps a Feature Request is necessary for that.

Comment: Nope :) `node.setActiveAndVisible();` does the job

Answer (score 1):

I knew it had to be available, it was just hidden in examples
`node.setActiveAndVisible();`